# Selenium Grid 2 or Hudson w/ slave nodes?

Tags: hudson, selenium-grid2

I am able to get my tests running on Hudson CI but have been interested to see if there's any clear performance difference between Selenium Grid 2 vs Hudson CI running slaves nodes?

I have yet to get xvfb working with Selenium Grid 2 while Hudson CI comes built in with the option to start XVNC server for each tests....

I would stick to Hudson CI but are there any clear benefits of using Selenium Grid 2? My tests are already written in Webdriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium Grid is NOT a replacement for Hudson with slave nodes. If you want to run your webdriver tests across multiple browsers IN parallel, then you need to use Grid. If you don't have this requirement, then you should continue with the existing method.

Now, if you want to run tests in parallel across multiple browsers then you should use Hudson **AND** Grid 2. Your tests will still continue to be triggered/scheduled and run from Hudson but it will utilize the Grid to run the test. It should be a combination of both these tools as Selenium Grid cant help you in most of the stuff which Hudson does.

Comment: Do you mean to boot up Selenium Grid Nodes in Hudson??

Comment: How are you starting your xvnc nodes using hudson now?

Comment: And how are you running your tests using Hudson now? Are you triggering the tests using ANT/MAVEN or something similar?

Comment: I've decided to just stick with Hudson CI for now. It's just that Hudson CI comes with extra features like scheduling jobs, email notification etc.

Comment: OK :). As said earlier, you cant replace Hudson with Grid. Both are for different purpose

Comment: BTW, if you are OK with running headless browser tests you can try HTMLUnitDriver which is part of Selenium2. That wouldn't require any display

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hudson to launch continuously your tests and Grid 2 to dispatch your tests to the browser/browsers you'd like.